Video/Image sequence playback doesn't work at all
I'm trying to use a rotoscoping addon in Blender, which means I need to open my video in Blender but the issue is that neither the .mov file or the .jpg image sequence actually plays. I just get the first frame and that's it !
Here's what it looks like in the UI
I have tested in Blender 3.6, 4.0 and 4.1. I have tried doubling the video playback memory, and disabling audio but I still get the issue !
Playback does work when setting the image sequence as a camera background or as an object texture though.
Does anyone have any idea why that could be happening ?
Thanks !

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

could you please tell how (step by step) how you imported your movie? ...or provide your blend file so we can check it out? thx.

It's unclear to me why you are using the image editor instead of the Movie Clip editor. But since you are there, did you try matching the length of the movie using this button?

Also please keep in mind that unless the video was encoded specifically for non-linear editing using a codec such as ProRes, or an all-I codec, you will see poor seeking performance due to the distance between i-frames.

I was not aware of this panel's existence, thanks a lot!! It works now. The reason i'm using the image editor is that the addon i'm using works in the image editor only! Thank you for all the info!
